# How to parse json and create nodes with foreach in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo, gql, neo4j-apoc

Sample json:

```
{
    "data": [
            {
                "file" : "1.txt",
                "type" : "text"
            },
            {
                "file" : "2.json",
                "type" : "json"
            },
            {
                "file" : "1.html",
                "type" : "html"
            }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to create 3 nodes with file and type as properties

I am using following query to create nodes in neo4j

```
WITH {json} AS document 
UNWIND document.data AS data
FOREACH (node in data| CREATE(m:`member`) SET m = node )
```

I am getting following error when i use py2neo driver:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SyntaxError'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query should be like -

```
 WITH {json} AS document
 FOREACH (node in document.data| CREATE(m:`memeber`) SET m = node )
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case *either* use UNWIND or FOREACH

```
WITH {json} AS document 
UNWIND document.data AS data
CREATE(m:`member`) SET m = data
```

or

```
WITH {json} AS document 
FOREACH (node in document.data | CREATE(m:`member`) SET m = node )
```